# Split comma separated multiple strings in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have row which is coming from csv file like

```
"abc@example.com","seattle,US","9999 00000"
```

Expected Output:

```
abc@example.com
seattle,US
9999 00000
```

Actual output when I do `string.Split(',')`:

```
"abc@example.com"
"seattle
US"
"9999 00000"
```

Comment: Show what you have done

Comment: Use a real csv parser not string.split

Comment: The `split` can not understand what you have on your mind - is work correctly for your output - if you need something different, just code it.

Comment: `using (var parser = new TextFieldParser("path"))
        {
            parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
            parser.Delimiters = new[] { "," };
            while (parser.PeekChars(1) != null)
            {
                string[] rowFields = parser.ReadFields();
            }
        }`

Comment: by the way - in the duplicate marked question aren't text qualifiers `"`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `"` character to qualify a column, you can split by `","`

```
string input = "\"abc@example.com\",\"seattle,US\",\"9999 00000\"";

string[] result = input.Trim('"').Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: Haven't downvoted. But this is not a very good approach. The delimiter is clearly a comma not the quotes. Your workaround works in this case though

Comment: @TimSchmelter but the quotes are even existing if there are no commas within their content

Comment: If every field in every line is surrounded by quotes, the splitting on "," seems fine to me.  What's wrong with this answer?